# add opacity to a css class

Tags: jquery, css, opacity, background-color

Is there a way to set opacity in a css class, in jquery you could do this:

```
$(result).parent().css({ 'background-color': '#eeeeee', 'opacity': '0.7' })
```

any way?
I need to put these to properties in a css class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are different `CSS` properties that are currently required for cross-browser compatibility.

```
filter:alpha(opacity=50); // For IE
-moz-opacity:0.5;         // Older versions of Mozilla
-khtml-opacity: 0.5;      // For Safari 1.x (I believe)
opacity: 0.5;             // General usage
```

Personally I'd stick with using `jQuery` to do this for you since they've already developed their method with multiple browsers in mind.

Comment: Thank you, if i want to use the jquery, i need to know how to red of those properties after and stick with the original ones. how can i do that  ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking.

Comment: after i add those new properties i have some function... after that i need to remove the properties i added.

Comment: add the sugested above as a class in your style sheet, then use `.addClass()` when you want to add it and (yes you guessed it...) `removeClass()` when you want to remove it.

Comment: In that case I'd simply change the class on the HTML element. If your current html is <div class="someOpacity">stuff</div>, then removing this class with jQuery will remove the styles.

Answer (score 1):

To set opacity in all major browsers do the following

HTML:

```
<div class="opacityElement"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.opacityElement {
    filter:alpha(opacity=50);  // IE
    -moz-opacity:0.5;          // Firefox
    -khtml-opacity: 0.5;       
    opacity: 0.5;         
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
.myClass{
  opacity:0.4;
  filter:alpha(opacity=40);
}
```

The `filter:alpha(opacity=40);` is for IE

Answer (score 0):

Yes, exactly the same way as you've done it with jQuery:

`.className { opacity: 0.7 }`

Note however that this will not work in Internet Explorer, so you need to add another property, `filter: alpha(opacity=70)`

Comment: Thanks, but it tells me that it is not a known css property.

Comment: What tells you that? The CSS3 spec tells me differently: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#transparency

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as a CSS class (HTML has classes, CSS has class selectors). It sounds like you mean a CSS rule-set though.

```
some selector {
    opacity: 0.7;
}
```

Comment: doesn't this contradict the answer above?